# Есть ли какие-нибудь способы реализации "Guards" в классах haskell?

Tags: классы, haskell, типы

Есть вот такая простая реализация моноида:

```
class (Eq t) => Monoid t where
  (<+>)   :: t -> t -> t -- бинарная алгебр. операция
  neutral :: t           -- нейтральный элемент
```

Однако, чтобы сделать его математически верным, также необходимо реализовать свойство ассоциативности операции.
Функция, проверяющая выполнение этого свойства могла бы выглядеть так:

```
isAssociative :: t -> t -> t-> Bool
isAssociative x y z
 |(x <+> y) <+> z == x <+> (y <+> z) = True
 |otherwise                          = False
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы подобную проверку можно было проводить автоматически.
А, может, я просто не понимаю самой сути классов в haskell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ассоциативность автоматически доказать можно для конечных типов (перебором, например). Для бесконечных типов (`String`, `Integer`...) перебор уже не сработает=)

Когда вы объявляете ваш тип инстансом какого-то алгебраического класса, то задача доказать, что все законы класса выполнены, лежит на программисте, а не на компиляторе.

Можно в качестве контрпримера сделать заведомо неправильный инстанс моноида (без ассоциативности):

```
module Main where

data MySum = MySum Integer deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Monoid MySum where
  mempty = MySum 0
  mappend (MySum a) (MySum b) = MySum (a-b)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ (MySum 3 `mappend` MySum 4) `mappend` MySum 5
  print $ MySum 3 `mappend` (MySum 4 `mappend` MySum 5)
```

Компилятор такой код с радостью принимает, резальтат работы программы, как не сложно догадаться,

```
> MySum (-6)
> MySum 4
```